# Process DateTime field value in SharePoint List Edit form

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, date-time, datepicker

I am working on a Item Update event receiver in a SharePoint document library. One of the fields in this library is a Date and Time (Date only format) field. When a user selects a date and clicks on the OK/save button, the `ItemUpdating` event receiver method must validate the date value by checking if the selected date is less than or equal to the current day's date. If the selected value is a future date, an error message is displayed, prompting the user to revise the date.

The code to extract before and after values on that field is:

```
// pre-updating
value = eventProperties.ListItem[eventProperties.ListItem.Fields[fieldName].InternalName];

// post-updating
value = eventProperties.AfterProperties[fieldName];
```

I selected a date of April 14, 2016 in the calendar control on the Edit Form page. Since it is a future date (today's date is March 12, 2016), I displayed an error message to alert the user of the constraint violation and also displaying the entered date and the current day's date. But the error message is displaying 04/13/2016 instead of 04/14/2016.

Regardless of how SharePoint stores the input value in the database, how do I get the value exactly as entered in the form so I can display that same value in any error message?

**Answer summary**

```
// Code to retrieve pre-updating value
value = eventProperties.ListItem[eventProperties.ListItem.Fields[fieldName].InternalName];
DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()).ToUniversalTime().ToShortDateString();

// Code to retrieve post-updating value
value = eventProperties.AfterProperties[fieldName];
DateTime dtValue = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb();
SPTimeZone timeZone = web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;
timeZone.LocalTimeToUTC(dtValue).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check out this post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7646335b-c3ed-4f24-a637-a5967575cc81/itemupdating-propertiesafterproperties-returning-incorrect-datetime?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Octavian

***Suggested edit 3/12/2016***

**Cause:**
The problem is caused by that: the time zone setting of the SharePoint  web is different from the windows client.

**Solution:**
The method to get the after properties with the actual hour is a little different. You should get the TimeZone of the Web, and then change the time value to the UTC time.

Comment: Please quote the main aspects of the article as well.